# ActionScript 3 draw bargraph tweening from bottom to top

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am drawing a bargraph chart  tweening in Flash Actionscript 3. Getting the input from the xml. Here the graph is drawn fine. But the graph is drawn from the top. My requirement is to draw( tween) from the X-axis(from bottom to top). I tried using TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE function, its drawing only the last element of the chart.

Below is the code

```
package 
{
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
    import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Graph extends Sprite
    {

    private var graphContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var xmlFile:XML;
    private var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    private var totalBars:int;
    private var tween:Tween;
    private var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

    public function Graph():void
    {
        tf.color = 0x666666;
        tf.size = 12;
        tf.font = "Helvetica";
    createGraphContainer();
    loadXML();
    createBars();
    }

    private function createGraphContainer():void
    {
        graphContainer.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xff00ff);
        graphContainer.graphics.moveTo(30, 30);
        graphContainer.graphics.lineTo(30, 170);
        graphContainer.graphics.lineTo(420, 170);
        addChild(graphContainer);           
    }
private function loadXML(file:String = "graph.xml"):void
    {
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(file));
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseXML);
    }

    private function parseXML(e:Event):void
    {
        xmlFile = new XML(e.target.data);       
            totalBars = 2;
    createBars();           
    }

    private function createBars():void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < totalBars; i++)
        {
        var label_txt = new int;                
        label_txt = 10+(i*15);
        var bar:Sprite = new Sprite();
            bar.graphics.beginFill(xmlFile.children()[i].@color);
        bar.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, xmlFile.@width, label_txt);
        bar.graphics.endFill();
            bar.x = 40 + (xmlFile.@width * i) + (10*i);
        bar.y = 170 - bar.height;

        var startingYandHeight:Number = bar.y + bar.height;
        var val:TextField = new TextField();
            val.defaultTextFormat = tf;
        val.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.RIGHT;
        val.text = label_txt ;
        val.x = 55 + (xmlFile.@width * i) + (10*i);
        val.y = 155 - bar.height;
        var myTween:Tween = new Tween(bar,"height",Strong.easeOut,0,bar.height ,5,true);                                    
        myTween.addEventListener( TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE, onChange);
        function onChange( e:TweenEvent ):void{
            bar.y = startingYandHeight - bar.height;
        }
        addChild(bar);
        addChild(val);

        }


        }


    }
}
```

---

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <graphs width="50"> 
        <graph name="Yellow" value="20" color="0xFDC13E"/>
        <graph name="Blue" value="40" color="0x25B7E2"/>
        <graph name="Green" value="60" color="0xB8CF36"/>
        <graph name="Red" value="100" color="0xE7473F"/>
        <graph name="Black" value="80" color="0x000000"/>
        <graph name="Brown" value="120" color="0xffffff"/>      
    </graphs>
```

please help me to draw the graph tweening from the bottom to top.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should understand coordinate system in flash.

[image: Coordinate System from flashexplained.com]

I would recommend to change your math accordingly. It isn't hard, but in the end you will have sufficient solution, and will not have any headaches, for example, when you will add additional elements like texts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it into a container, and give that container `scaleY=-1`, should do.

```
public var graph:Graph; // initialize elsewhere
...
this.addChild(graph);
this.scaleY = -1;
```